# Upload files on ipad with fine-uploader with icab mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, django, fine-uploader

I'm trying to upload files to a server on my iPad with FineUploader. I'm using icab mobile to select other files than images. But when I select a file (with the iCab uploader) the file won't be added to the upload queue.

When i set icab mobile to iOs uploader (images only) the file will upload.

(iCab mobile let's you add files to it's own filesystem and can upload those files (when the iCab uploader is selected in the settings)).

Is there any solution to fix my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you seeing in the console with `debug: true`?

Comment: I don't know how to check the console on my iPad. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that sadly doesn't work for the iCab mobile browser. The problem appears in that browser (chosen for the fileuploader)

Comment: Hmm.  I would expect iCab to simply be a webkit wrapper, like Chrome.  I guess you can only remote-debug Safari on iOS?  That's unfortunate.

Comment: Yes I could see the console in Safari only. I can try a few other apps and then I'll tell the results.

Comment: It indeed only works with Safari. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with icab (this is the first time I've heard of it).  So, I'm not sure how to best address this.  Does icab offer support for their products?

Comment: I will contact iCab and if I know the problem I'll let you know

Comment: I've had contact with a developer of iCab. He said they indeed change the input file, they change it to a input button (so iCab can work around the iOS restrictions). Do you think it will be possible with some changes in the FineUploader script? Here is some more info he sent: [link](http://www.icab.de/blog/2012/08/02/uiwebview_file_upload_support/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the recent comments, and a [post from icab's blog](http://www.icab.de/blog/2012/08/02/uiwebview_file_upload_support/), icab is changing  the file input element into a button element.  This is a problem for Fine Uploader, and something that icab should absolutely not be doing on versions of iOS that actually support the file input element (iOS6+).  Until icab fixes this issue in their software, Fine Uploader (and any other HTML/JavaScript upload library) will not function correctly when icab is involved.

Comment: But iOS can only upload images and thats what their app changes. You can upload every file you want with their input type. But it makes it hard for jQuery uploaders I guess.

Comment: That's not what their app does.  You can't upload files that don't exist.  iOS only houses image and video files.  What their app does is allow you to upload in iOS5 and older, where the file input element was not yet supported.

Comment: You can add files to their app, they have an own filesystem and with their filesystem you can upload documents. It's not only for older versions of an iPad but also for file uploads. This is from their site: "Using the upload capabilities of the iOS will work on almost all web pages but is limited to photos and videos from the photo album and is only working under iOS 6 and later. Using iCab's own upload capability will allow to upload all file types, even under iOS 5, but it can not work on all web sites."

Comment: Ok.  That doesn't change my answer here.

Comment: Ok. So there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Nothing short of removing icab, assuming manipulation of file input elements is crucial to their product.